# Problem setting Zend_Form_Element ID to "id"

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I find that when I try doing

```
$this->addElement('hidden', 'id');
```

And run, I get something like

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object in D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Form.php on line 3318

Call Stack:
    0.0002     329712   1. {main}() D:\Projects\Tickle\public\index.php:0
    0.0726    1393760   2. Zend_Application->run() D:\Projects\Tickle\public\index.php:26
    0.0726    1393760   3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Application.php:366
    0.0727    1393816   4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php:97
    0.1787    2026520   5. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Front.php:954
    0.1860    2144464   6. Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:295
    0.2089    2771352   7. Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Action.php:523
    0.2090    2772208   8. Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php:277
    0.2091    2772208   9. Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php:957
    0.2099    2772400  10. Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php:918
    0.2099    2772400  11. Zend_View_Abstract->render() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php:897
    0.2100    2813576  12. Zend_View->_run() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\View\Abstract.php:880
    0.2103    2814016  13. include('D:\Projects\Tickle\application\views\scripts\projects\edit.phtml') D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\View.php:108
    0.2103    2814016  14. Zend_Form->__toString() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Form.php:0
    0.2103    2814016  15. Zend_Form->render() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Form.php:2916
    0.2117    2825200  16. Zend_Form_Decorator_FormElements->render() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Form.php:2900
    0.2120    2827128  17. Zend_Form->rewind() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Form.php:0
    0.2120    2827128  18. Zend_Form->_sort() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Form.php:3225
```

When I try doing

```
$this->addElement('hidden', 'id2');
```

it works

My Zend_Form http://pastie.org/1425012 for reference

Comment: check line 63 of you provided source code

Comment: @ArneRie, whats wrong with line 63? I am adding an element of type text with name of id?

Comment: and you get an error if you try to add second element with the name "id" (your hidden field)

Comment: post your Application_Form_FormsBase too

Comment: @Keyne here you go http://pastie.org/1427688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally direcovered =)

Change your property name `$id` to `$_id` (and also the references `$this->_id`). Zend form make use of the property name when you define the element. So, always use an underline or something else to diferenciate the names.

```
protected $_minimalMode;
protected $_id;
```

Comment: So I guess theres no way to name an element "id"?

Comment: Actually you can name with whatever you want. The point is, if you're using Zend_Form you cannot use class properties without an underline. So, you'll keep your field name with ID and will change the property name to `$_id` (not the field name), because one thing is the property and another is your element called `id`. Notice that for each element created you can access using $this->elementName. This is the reason of the conflict.